# is possible to link microsoft account with extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

every time i  download visual studio code i have to re download all my extensions, there is some way for save config and extensions on hotmail account?

Answer (score 0):

Before you update VS code dump your extension list at the command line.

```
To make it easier to automate and configure VS Code, it is possible to list, install, and uninstall extensions from the command line.
```

When you download an extension, put the extension on a share. Then always install the extension from that share.

```
Some users prefer to download an extension once from the Marketplace and then install it multiple times from a local share. This is useful when there are connectivity concerns or if your development team wants to use a fixed set of extensions.

From: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery
```